# Saving and Retrieving data for TreeView in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, treeview

I am creating a TreeView which has only THREE Level of nodes. Now I want to get objects from this treeview and save data to database. I also want to retrieve data to show in that tree view.  How can I prepare objects from TreeView to save data to database and how can I select data to prepare objects to load data into that treeview.

My database table object is:

```
public class CampaignRuleSetup
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Values { get; set; }               
    }
```

And the TreeView diagram is:
[image]

Comment: What do you know about hierarchical data?

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything about hierarchical data.